# Dont start new activity on new intent, take the old activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Im using NFC and im working with intents. When a NFC Tag is discovered
i start my NFCActivity.

```
<activity
    android:name="controller.NFCActivity" 
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

The NFCActivity is an Activity without a UI. It starts my NFCReaderTask.

```
String action = intent.getAction();

if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    NFCDataDevice dataDevice = new NFCDataDevice();
    dataDevice.setCurrentTag(tagFromIntent);

    byte[] systemInfoAnswer = NFCCommand.sendGetSystemInfoCommandCustom(tagFromIntent, new NFCDataDevice());

    if (NDEFHelper.decodeSystemInfoResponse(systemInfoAnswer, new NFCDataDevice())) {
        NFCReaderTask nfcReaderTask = new NFCReaderTask(this, this, dataDevice);
        nfcReaderTask.execute();
    } 
}
```

When the ReaderTask is finished my callback method `onNFCReaderTaskCompleted` in my 
NFCActivity is called and i do that:

```
public void onNFCReaderTaskCompleted(Long time, String value) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NFCResultActivity.class);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    newIntent.putExtra(Globals.KEY_NFC, true);
    newIntent.putExtra(Globals.KEY_TIME, time);
    newIntent.putExtra(Globals.KEY_VALUE, value);

    this.startActivity(newIntent);
    this.finish();
}
```

That is fine for the first time a NFC Tag is discovered. What i now want is to dont 
start a new NFCResultActivity always. When the NFCResultActivity is active i just
want to call a method of that NFCResultActivity to set the new data and not to completely 
create a new Activity.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it differently.

I deleted my NFCActivity and changed my NFCResultActivity to do the intent listening:

```
<activity
        android:name="controller.NFCResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nfcresult" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
```

I now start the NFCReaderTask in my NFCResultActivity and i added this method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    this.setIntent(intent);
    this.resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

To update my data without creating a new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this line.

```
  newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

or

```
 <activity
android:name="controller.NFCActivity" 
android:launchMode="singleTop" >
```

Comment: ehm that actually makes it worse. first it does not pretend from starting the activity over and over again and second when i manually start my NFCResultActivity and than place a tag i have two NFCResultActivities at the top.

Comment: remove this flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|

Comment: <activity
android:name="controller.NFCActivity" 
android:launchMode="singleTop" > 

use this in your manifest and remove flag from intent